# PHP Gameserver Query

Tags: php

I have a script I found that queries SRCDS gameservers and outputs information such as hostname, IP, connected players etc. (Note I have edited it so it only displayes currently connected players and map) I would like the script to first ping the server to check if it is online or not and then continue with the queries.

**PHP Script**

```
function source_query($ip){
$cut = explode(":", $ip);
$HL2_address = $cut[0];
$HL2_port = $cut[1];

$HL2_command = "\377\377\377\377TSource Engine Query\0";

$HL2_socket = fsockopen("udp://".$HL2_address, $HL2_port, $errno, $errstr,3);
fwrite($HL2_socket, $HL2_command); 
$JunkHead = fread($HL2_socket,4);
$CheckStatus = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);

if($CheckStatus["unread_bytes"] == 0)return 0;

$do = 1;
while($do){
    $str = fread($HL2_socket,1);
    $HL2_stats.= $str;
    $status = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);
    if($status["unread_bytes"] == 0){
           $do = 0;
    }
}
fclose($HL2_socket);

$x = 0;
while ($x <= strlen($HL2_stats)){
    $x++;
    $result.= substr($HL2_stats, $x, 1);    
}

// ord ( string $string );
$result = str_split($result);
$info['network'] = ord($result[0]);$char = 1;
while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['name'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['map'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['dir'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['description'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
$info['appid'] = ord($result[$char].$result[($char+1)]);$char += 2;        
$info['players'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
$info['max'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
$info['bots'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
$info['dedicated'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
$info['os'] = chr(ord($result[$char]));$char++;    
$info['password'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
$info['secure'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;    
while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['version'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}

return $info;
}
```

**Display code**

```
include 'status.php'; // name of file including above script
$q = source_query('ip:port'); // replaced with real IP address and port
echo "Players: " .$q['players'];
echo "/" .$q['max'];
echo "<br>";
echo "Map: ".$q['map'];
```

To clarify: this script works fine in returning currently connected players and current map being played when the server is online. When the server is offline is loads for a while then just prints

```
Players: /
Map:
```

I want the server to be pinged beforehand. If it is online it does as above, but if it is offline I want it to echo "Offline", remove the

```
Players: /
Map:
```

and do not continue with the query to minimise the length of time it takes to load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely won't speed things up a whole lot, but it's probably better than what you have now at least.  However, I'll note that the PHP manual says this in reference to the `unread_bytes` usage: `Note: You shouldn't use this value in a script.`  You could also decrease the timeout (the last parameter) on the call to `fsockopen`.

```
function ping($host)
{
    exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
}

$HL2_command = "\377\377\377\377TSource Engine Query\0";

if(!ping($HL2_address))
{
    return 0;
}

$HL2_socket = fsockopen("udp://".$HL2_address, $HL2_port, $errno, $errstr,3);
```

**Display code**

```
include 'status.php'; // name of file including above script
$q = source_query('ip:port'); // replaced with real IP address and port

if($q === 0)
{
    echo "Offline";
}
else
{
    echo "Players: " .$q['players'];
    echo "/" .$q['max'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Map: ".$q['map'];
}
```

Comment: This works, provided the server is online or exists. However, it doesn't do as mentioned above. If the server is offline, it tries to query it which takes a long time. That is why I want to include the ping feature to check if it is online or not before any queries are made!

Comment: @JakeGriffin What exactly is your definition of "offline"? The entire server is down? A specific port is unreachable?  You get an empty response?  It's possible that the determination of whether or not the server is "offline" could take a little bit of time.  That's why I suggested lowering the timeout.

Comment: By "offline" I mean all of the above. For example, if I chose 192.168.1.1:80 and there was nothing running on port 80, it takes a long while for the page to load "offline". Would it not be more feasible to ping the address beforehand to check is something is actually there and responding before querying it? I don't really know if this makes sense. Besides, the timeout is set to 4 seconds yet it takes far longer for the page to load if it is querying something that isn't there/offline. Take a look at [this](http://www.griffingaming.co.uk/test.php) - note how it takes a long time to load.

Comment: @JakeGriffin Check my update.  It uses functionality from [this post](http://www.darian-brown.com/php-ping-script-to-check-remote-server-or-website/). You might also look into [stream_set_timeout](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php), as it may be the `fwrite` and `fread` calls that are taking a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far, however your update now causes it to say "Offline" no matter what! Granted, it is alot faster now :P

Comment: @JakeGriffin As the linked post mentions, the function requires that you have the `exec()` function available to you. If you are running in safe mode, then you do not. You should read through the post and the accompanying comments if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) of `fsockopen`, especially for UDP connections, you should consider to do more error handling:

> Warning
>
> UDP sockets will sometimes appear to have opened without an error,
> even if the remote host is unreachable. The error will only become
> apparent when you read or write data to/from the socket. The reason
> for this is because UDP is a "connectionless" protocol, which means
> that the operating system does not try to establish a link for the
> socket until it actually needs to send or receive data.